# Databricks and Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure-blob-storage, databricks, azure-databricks, mount

I am running this on databricks notebook

```
dbutils.fs.ls("/mount/valuable_folder")
```

I am getting this error

> Caused by: StorageException: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

I tried using `dbutils.fs.refreshMounts()`

to get any updates in azure blob storage, but still getting above error.

Answer (score 0):

Such errors most often arise when credentials that you have used for mounting are expired - for example, SAS is expired, storage key is rotated, or service principal secret is expired. You need to unmount the storage using `dbutils.fs.unmount` and mount it again with `dbutils.fs.mount`. `dbutils.fs.refreshMounts()` just refreshes a list of mounts in the backend, it doesn't recheck for credentials.

Comment: dbutils.fs.unmount - I forgot to mention that I did try this as well

Comment: Then recheck credentials